# How does one encode a model in x-www-form-urlencoded format so it can be consumed by an ASP.NET MVC action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Assume I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller that looks like this

```
public class MyController : Contoller
{
    public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
    {
        /* doing some stuff with the model */
    }
}
```

The model looks like this

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public ThatModel Property1 { get; set; }
    public List<ThisModel> BunchOfThisModel { get; set; }
}

public class ThatModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
    public string Property6 { get; set; }
}

public class ThisModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Does ASP.NET MVC or .NET (v4 is ok, v4.5 not) provide any built-in means to encode a model (say MyModel in this case) so that it can be sent to an action as form url encoded (aka x-www-form-urlencoded)? An example would be "property1=abc&property2=def". However, ASP.NET MVC has its own way to deal with nested models etc when decoding the request back to the model.  Assume I'm simulating a browser using the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)/[WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx) APIs provided since .NET 1.1.

In essence, I'd like to build up requests in tests to verify that

1. some data is excluded through binding, if needed
2. the anti forgery token is set, if needed
3. malicious data is handled accordingly

Note: ASP.NET Web API is not being used at this stage. Because I'm writing (integration) tests for an existing application, sending the model as JSON, XML or another alternative format isn't applicabile to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood this question correctly, but provided you are 'POST'ing that data (from JSON?) then it is able to build up the model using a best-guess process.

Property names are matched, so if you sent (guessing the duplicate Property1 is actually Property3 here)

```
{
  Property1="this", 
  Property2="that", 
  Property3={Property1="this3", ....}, 
  BunchOfThisModel=[{Property1="bunchthis"},{....}]
}
```

This would populate your POCO with whatever names matched. If you left out a property (i.e. Property2) it would take on it's `default(T)` value.

Sending your object model in a GET request would be much more complicated, you could base64 the JSON string, and then parse it on server which is popular approach, but given it's a complex model POST might work best for your intentions.

You can also use a CustomBinder (a [good article is here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584)). You can also control which properties are bound to your POCO object by using the `BindAttribute` with the Exclude/Include options.

Hope I haven't missed the point and this proves useful :)

Comment: I was interested in how to serialize a model so it can be sent to the server in "x-www-form-urlencoded" format and be processed by an ASP.NET MVC Action, similar to a browser form posting data to that action without having to change the server. Perhaps my question is a tad unclear.

Comment: Ahh yes - sorry for misunderstand :) At the risk of misunderstanding it again... Can you just use the FormCollection property instead?

Comment: I think you are heading in the right direction.  The question is really how to serialize a model into a FormCollection on a client so that it can be deserialized on the server back to that model.  Once know that I can figure out how to convert a FormCollection to a "x-www-form-urlencoded" request.

Comment: Yeh, I'm not sure that there is anything like that in the Framework, but I'd be interested if you did find it. Guess you're looking at writing serialization for a bunch of key/value pairs in to a url encoded request and sending it as the body. Sorry couldn't help more.

Comment: Hope this post helps from phil haack - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx